# Ubuntu CUPS printing

Tags: printing

I've been fiddling with the for the whole day and couldn't figure out what the problem is due to my lack of knowledge about Ubuntu.

It all started with me trying to set up a network printer in the command line by following a post (previously someone has setup two network printers to this computer but it is extremely unstable - I get my printout several hours after I submitted the printing job hence I decided to setup the printer again):

```
>/etc/init.d/cups stop
>update-rc.d -f cupsys remove
>lpstat -a
```

Now at this point `lpstat -a` showed me two printers I was originally connected to this computer.

However after I added the server name to `/etc/cups/client.conf`, everthing seemed to be acting strangely:
`lpstat -a` gives "no such file or directory" message. And I can't continue with the instructions on the post since the next one `lpoptions -d printerName` wouldn't work.

Then I tried to uninstall cups by `sudo apt-get purge cups` and reinstall it by `sudo apt-get install cups` and started it by `/etc/init.d/cups start`

I also noticed that in the Printers setting, I couldn't add printers anymore. "Sorry! The system printing service doesn't seem to be available" is waht it says.

the command `lpstat` gives "`lpstat: Bad file descriptor`"

I assume CUPS is just one of many ways of setting up printing. There might be more than one services(daemon) running?

By the way (if this also be a hint for diagnose the problem): I can get to localhost:631 the CUPS web interface but I can't get into any of the links on there.

I'm getting exhausted by trying different ways that are suggested by the Internet. Could anyone give me a hint on whether this problem is caused by CUPS and the working principle of printing in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

try restarting the CUPS service

```
sudo service cups stop && sudo service cups start
```